# MicroFront Ends Recommendations

Tags: javascript

Any one having ideas on using Self contained systems in angular 4 ?

Objective : 
Divide Angular in to sub applications such a way that each sub application can be self deployed & Can be written by a separate Team.

Comment: @Izzy: correct me if i am wrong . i am asking software which can help me to achieve Micro services in the front end. ! Help me as to repharase what part of the question.

Comment: Reopened – as now it's clearly on-topic (to me). As this is completely outside my area of profession, I've got to leave improvements to others :) Good luck!

Comment: Why not just have each team write its own Angular application and not care about the others? Each Angular application can be deployed normally. If the different applications need any kind of collaboration, please edit your question to detail how.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul the question here is about : Integrating independent applications in to 1...! Example : App integration of header + Footer + Dashboard

Comment: Please edit your question to make that clearer. Explain what each application is, and how data is shared.

Comment: i mentioned Self contained systems ! The term SCS speaks the same thing!!! Question here is implementation of SCS or microfrontends in Angular.